# Excel - Extract text from multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to fill in a column ("mode of communication") based if a value is present in other columns.

This is how the rows and columns appear now.

```
+------+----------------+----------------+------------+----------------+
| Mode | In Person      | Email          | IM         | Phone          |
+------+----------------+----------------+------------+----------------+
|      | In person < 5  |                |            |                |
+------+----------------+----------------+------------+----------------+
|      |                | Email 10 - 15  |            |                |
+------+----------------+----------------+------------+----------------+
|      |                |                | IM < 5 min |                |
+------+----------------+----------------+------------+----------------+
|      |                |                |            | Phone 10 - 15  |
+------+----------------+----------------+------------+----------------+
|      |                |                | IM < 5 min |                |
+------+----------------+----------------+------------+----------------+
```

What I want is to use a formula to get it to scan through the thousands of rows and insert text into the Mode of Communication column based on if there is an entry in "In Person", "Email", "IM", or "Phone", and then to ideally create a separate column with the duration.

```
+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+-------+----+-------+
| Mode of Communication | Time Spent  | In Person | Email | IM | Phone |
+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+-------+----+-------+
| In Person             | < 5 min     |           |       |    |       |
+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+-------+----+-------+
| Email                 | 10 - 15 min |           |       |    |       |
+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+-------+----+-------+
| IM                    | < 5 min     |           |       |    |       |
+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+-------+----+-------+
| Phone                 | < 5 min     |           |       |    |       |
+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+-------+----+-------+
| In Person             | 10 - 15 min |           |       |    |       |
+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+-------+----+-------+
```

I have been trying to use VLOOKUP. All the rows and columns are on the same sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in the 'Mode of Communication' column:

`=IF(C2<>"","In Person",IF(D2<>"","Email",IF(E2<>"","IM",IF(F2<>"","Phone",""))))`

Put this in the 'Time Spent' column:

`=IF(C2<>"",SUBSTITUTE(C2,"In person ","")&" min",IF(D2<>"",SUBSTITUTE(D2,"Email ","")&" min",IF(E2<>"",SUBSTITUTE(E2,"IM ","")&" min",IF(F2<>"",SUBSTITUTE(F2,"Phone ","")&" min",""))))`

These assume that column A is Mode of Communication and column B is Time Spent.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a new blank column between column A and column B.

In A2,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$1:F$1, MATCH("zzz", C2:F2)), TEXT(,))
```

In B2,

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(REPLACE(INDEX(C2:F2, MATCH("zzz", C2:F2)), 1, LEN(A2), TEXT(,))), TEXT(,))
```

Fill down.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions I see is concatenating all column and parse.

For example in column " Mode of Communication" you can use concatenate(inperson,email,im,phone) and then parse the data.

Use this formula in Mode of communication column: Cell A2
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(C2,D2,E2,F2),B2,""))

Time Spent Column: Cell B2
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(C2,D2,E2,F2),"In person",""),"Email",""),"IM",""),"Phone",""))